# Start a command and if it doesn't work start another

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to start acrobat from my software.
At this moment I'm using the following command:

```
cmd /c start AcroRd32.exe /t filename
```

But now acrobat sometimes updates to 64 bit version and then AcroRd32.exe doesn't exists anymore.
So we have to start acrobat.exe instead:

```
cmd /c start acrobat.exe /t filename
```

But we are working with a lot of clients with different computers and maybe different versions of acrobat. That is also why we don't specify an install path.

So is there a way to say in one command line entry (not a script) to start AcroRd32.exe and if this doesn't work start immediately acrobat.exe instead?
So something like:

```
cmd /c start AcroRd32.exe /t filename | if not 1 is ok then cmd /c start acrobat.exe /t filename
```

Comment: Why are you using `cmd /C start`? why aren't you just starting `Acro*.exe` directly? And aren't Acrobat and Acrobat Reader different things?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('where autoruns64.exe autorunsc64.exe 2^>nul') DO CMD /c START "" "%%b" &GOTO done
ECHO NOT found!
:done
GOTO :eof
```

Note: `START` command : extra pair of quotes. This sets the title of the `START`ed session, otherwise the first `"quoted string"` is used.

`"%%b"` is used in case the path to the executable (I used `autoruns`) contains a space.

The first argument to `where` is the preferred target.

`where` examines the `path` for filenames matching its arguments and lists them. The `for /f` reads the list and on the first match found, executes the `START`. If no match is found,an error message is produced by `WHERE`, which is suppressed by the `2^>nul`.

Edit: one-line version

```
FOR /f "delims=" %b IN ('where autoruns64.exe autorunsc64.exe 2^>nul') DO CMD /c START "" "%b" &exit
```

Posted as a batch file because it's easier to re-run during testing.

`WHERE` locates files on the `PATH` and lists them
`START` locates files on the `PATH` and executes the first one found.

The `PATH` is the list of directories that will be examined by `START`, in the order in which they will be searched for the required executable, so `WHERE` examines that list of directories for the target executable, it does not search all of the drives in the hope of finding it.

Comment: This isn't a good answer to my question, first I asked no script, and you gave me a script while I asked for one command line.
The second problem if I read correctly is that you search for the path for the exe, but I don't want to search for it, it isn't in the Path, but you can start it with start in front of it.

Comment: I have tried your one line version now, if I do "start acrobat.exe" it works
but if I put acrord32.exe and acrobat.exe in the where clause it doesn't work, he doesn't find the files

Comment: I established  `acrotest1.bat` and `acrobat1.bat`  in a directory on the path, and successfully used this command :  'for /f "delims=" %b in (''where acrotest1.bat acrobat1.bat 2^>nul'') do @start "" cmd /c "%b"&exit' . It worked happily when the two `where` parameters were swapped (first-occurring was preferred) and when the parameters were changed to non-existent executables (ran nothing, obviously).

Comment: You said your bat files are in a directory on the path, but acrobat or acrord32 is not on my path variable, however if I use start acrobat.exe it starts. I'm not in the directory where the exe file stands, if I use your solution this doesn't work, probably because this is looking for the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally even on 64bit it was still Acrord32 for the free reader to avoid such dual name problems / complication and the 32bit or 64bit full product was start Acrobat.exe

However Adobe did not help by using version specifics within the registry so a query there would generally produce differing results ! Microsoft start adding enhancements as to where or how simple launchers may be deployed so the location now gets cloudier (pun :-)

However the traditional ask the registry works best except for my portable
version (where /r h:\ acrord32.exe is very slow on a TB drive and it was not on that one anyway, it was on a network drive!).

Simplest way I can think of via cmd to find an installed copy is:-

```
cmd /v:on  /c "where acro*.exe>temp.txt&&set /p acroexe=<temp.txt&&if exist !acroexe! (!acroexe! /t %filename%)"
```

there is little use of errorlevel since the fail will simply report

```
> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Priority will be the **first** match within %path%

You also need to consider where temp.txt will be written perhaps "%tmp%\delme.txt"

Potential "Gotcha" is if first match finds something like AcrobatUpdater.exe

To avoid random acro's best use

```
cmd /v:on  /c "where /f acrord32.exe acrobat.exe>temp.txt&&set /p acroexe=<temp.txt&&if exist !acroexe! (!acroexe! /t %filename%)"
```

actually since all you desire is start one or the other then

```
start "Reader" acrord32.exe /t "filename.pdf" "printer name"||start "Editor" acrobat.exe /t "filename.pdf" "printer name"
```

The downside to this last method is Windows will raise a GUI error if acrord32 cannot "start" Thus gui warning needs to be dismissed before the second option can be run and start. In that case START cannot be told to be silent on error.

**Finally** make your choice from above or use a hybrid approach

where /f acrord32.exe... || start acrobat.exe.. will not warn user on first fail but only on second if both missing.